# Filter data according to input from child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a List of Users which I want to filter during the user Types in letters in a Textfield.

In my Child component which contains the Input field I pass the input Up via props:

```
 onEnter(event){
    console.log("ENTER")
   // console.log(event.target.value)
    this.props.filterEmployee(event.target.value);
}
```

In my Container Component I take the value

```
filterEmployee(val){
    console.log(val)
   // const allUser = this.props.allUser.allUserData;

   allUser .forEach(function(user){
       if(user.userNameLast.indexOf(val) != -1){
           console.log(user) //works
       }
    });
}
```

The `allUser` is an array of data connected from my **Redux-store** to the Container Component.

This data are also used to display the list of Users initialzied on `componentWillMount`.

```
 render() {
    console.log("administration")
    console.log(this.props)

    const allUser = this.props.allUser.allUserData;


    return (
        <div id="employeeAdministration">
            <h1>Mitarbeiter Verwaltung</h1>
            <EmployeeAdministrationFilterList
                filterEmployee={this.filterEmployee.bind(this)}
            />
            {/* suchfeld - Name, Department mit checkbox*/}
            <ul>
                {allUser.length != 0 ? allUser.map(function (item, i) {
                    console.log(item)
                    return <li key={i}>
                        <UserCard
                            userData={item}
                            displayPersonalInfo={true}
                            showRequestDates={false}
                            showChangePassword={false}
                        />
                    </li>
                })
                    : ""
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

The problem now is, that I don´t know how to tell the `<UserCard />` that the data has changed. How can I pass the data from the function to the `render()` function?

What would be the way to go here?

EDIT:

I have also tried to go the way via the reducer, but so far it didn´t worked.

```
 filterEmployee(val){
    console.log(val)
    const {dispatch} = this.props;
    dispatch(filterAllUser(val));
}
```

And the Reducer (which is not working)

```
function allUser(state = {allUserData: []}, action){
switch (action.type){
    case 'REQUEST_ALL_USER':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetching: true
        });
    case 'RECEIVE_ALL_USER':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetching: false,
            allUserData: action.items
        });
    case 'FILTER_ALL_USER':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            allUserData: state.allUserData.filter(user => user.userNameLast !== action.filter )
        });
    default:
        return state
}
}
```

And here is the Code how the store is connected to the component

```
 EmployeeAdministration.PropTypes = {
   allUserData: PropTypes.array
  };

  const mapStateToProp = state => ({
     allUser: state.allUser
   });

   export default connect(mapStateToProp)(EmployeeAdministration)
```

When trying this, the result is [Console output of state object](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160902/jgo556h7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example should be able to demonstrate a basic workflow: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/03jj0y7u/6/).

Basically, `Redux` has a `one-way-dataflow`. The data (here is `Users` in the `store`) is flowed from the root component to the sub-components.

Whenever you want to change the value of `Users` inside whichever component, you create an `Action` and `dispatch` the action to some corresponding `reducer`. The `reducer` updates the `store` and pass it from top to bottom.

For example, you want to filter all users whose name contains `"Jo"`:

### Action creator

Pass the `Action creators` into the components. An `action` is a plain object with format like `{type: "FILTER_ALL_USERS", query: "Jo"}`. Here the passing is line 73:

```
<Users users={this.props.users} actions={this.props.actions}></Users>
```

Inside the component `Users`, we can call `this.props.actions.filter()` to create an `action`.

### Dispatch the action created

This `action` is automatically dispatched by `redux` because we have `bindActionCreators` in Line 93:

```
// Map the action creator and dispatcher
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: Redux.bindActionCreators(userActions, dispatch),
    dispatch
  }
}
```

### Reducer to handle the action

All reducers will be informed about this action, but a particular one will handle it (based on its `type`), Line 20:

```
case 'FILTER_ALL_USERS': 
  return allUsers.filter(user => user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(action.query.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
```

### Re-render

The reducer will return a brand-new object as the new `store`, which will be passed by `Redux` from the root of the component. All `render` functions in sub-components will be called.

Comment: I have updated my Q and added my try to do it via the reducer. But I pretty new to this syntax hand can´t get it working. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I created an example for you. About 200 lines of code. But seems unavoidable as `Redux` is a bit complex by design.